# How to change variable name in runtime

Tags: java

How can I concatenate object names with string or integer in java can anyone have an idea.

```
Button[] digitButtons = new Button[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int buttonInd = i;
    Button btn0+i = new Button(Integer.toString(i));
    digitButtons[i] = btn0+i;
    digitButtons[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button pressed " + ((Button) e.getSource()).getText());
            System.out.println("button clicked " + ((Control)e.getSource()).getId());
            lastClickedIndex = buttonInd;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You want to add the text "e"?

Comment: `Button btn0+i = new Button(Integer.toString(i));` You do not need that, actually. It's going to be a new variable in each iteration. Its name has no effect on the rest of the code, as far as I can tell. You could even just do `digitButtons[i] = new Button(Integer.toString(i));`

Comment: Oh and no, danymically concatenating variable names is not supported. Every time you feel the need to have it, use a collection (array, list, ...). - Which you are already doing here, so you're good.

Comment: actually, I need to every object have a specific name in the array.

Comment: in this part: "Button pressed " + ((Button) e.getSource()).getText(); you are already concatenating Strings so it seems to me you know how to

Comment: _"actually, I need to every object have a specific name in the array."_ - no you don't. The `Button` type has all the properties you need to uniquely identify it.

Comment: is there any way?

Comment: Any way to what? Have dynamically name variables? No. To uniquely identify Button instances? Yes. For example: A Button is-a Component, which has a Name: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your buttons in a `HashMap<String, Button>`, and this way you could name your buttons and rename them as many times as you want. **You cannot rename variables in runtime.**

Here is an example:

```
// this will keep the variables this way: [ "btn01" -> buttonObject1, "btn02" -> buttonObject2 ...]
HashMap<String, Button> buttonHashMap = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    final int buttonInd = i;
    String buttonName = "btn0" + i;
    Button buttonObject = new Button(Integer.toString(i));
    
    buttonHashMap.put(buttonName, buttonObject);

    // The .get(buttonName) gets the specific Button that you need!
    buttonHashMap.get(buttonName).setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Button pressed " + ((Button) e.getSource()).getText());
            System.out.println("button clicked " + ((Control)e.getSource()).getId());
            lastClickedIndex = buttonInd;
        }
    });
}
```